# Trouble with jsconfig.json in VSCode (dependencies intellisense on import not working)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm having some trouble finding out the proper way to set the `jsconfig.json` file in my React / Firebase project.

**Root folder structure:**

```
functions/
node_modules/
src/

.babelrc
.firebaserc
jsconfig.json
firebase.json
package.json
wepack.config.js
```

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I'm almost sure that I've been using it like this without any problems before.

I can't tell exactly when it happened, but right now I'm **not getting intellisense for my installed dependencies.**

[image]

If I delete `jsconfig.json` or simply rename to deactivate it, it goes back to normal:

[image]

---

**QUESTION**

What am I doing wrong? How is the proper way to set `jsconfig.json` to get correct intellisense on my current project? Do I have to use it at all? What benefits does it bring to the table?

---

**VSCode info and extensions list:**

```
Version: 1.32.3 (user setup)
Commit: a3db5be9b5c6ba46bb7555ec5d60178ecc2eaae4
Date: 2019-03-14T23:43:35.476Z
Electron: 3.1.6
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

[image]

Comment: Try enabling [checkJs type checking](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript) by adding a `// @ts-check` comment to the top of the file. Are there any errors reported for the import?

Comment: No errors. Just doesn't work. `//@ts-check` didn't solve it either.